# Finding a general derivative of $(n-1)th$ order for a function.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, induction

I was in the middle of an exercise, and I now have to simplify/determine a general formula for the following derivative:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z+i)^{-n}\right]
\end{equation*}
**What I have done:** After giving some values to $n$, I noticed the following pattern:
\begin{equation*}
n =2: -2(z+i)^{-3} \\
n=3: 12(z+i)^{-5} \\
n =4: -120(z+i)^{-7}
\end{equation*}
Which made me write the following general formula:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z+i)^{-n}\right] = (-1)^{n+1}(z+i)^{-(2n-1)}\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}(n+k)
\end{equation*}
And this is where my problems begin. I am having trouble proving this formula through mathematical induction and I don't even know if the productory part is correct at all (it seems correct for the cases I stated above).

Comment: It might be easier to derive a formula for $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z+i)^{-k}\right]$ and then set $k=n$.

Comment: @MartinR I have tried it, but it still gets me to the same formula, which I am having trouble with. Thanks for your help btw :D

Comment: $(z+i)^{-(n+1)}$ should be $(z+i)^{-(2n-1)}$, otherwise your result seems to be correct.

Comment: That's right indeed! Thanks for your feedback

Comment: what is "the productory part"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich when I refer "productory part" I mean the following: \begin{equation*} \prod_{k=0}^{n-2}(n+k)\end{equation*}

Comment: It's called a "product"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed integer $k$ is
$$
\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z+i)^{-k}\right] = (-k)(-k-1)\cdots(-k-(n-2))(z+i)^{-k-(n-1)} \\
= (-1)^{n-1}k(k+1)\cdots(k+n-2)(z+i)^{-k-n+1}
$$
which can be proven with induction over $n$. Setting $k=n$ gives
$$
\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z+i)^{-n}\right] = (-1)^{n-1}n(n+1)\cdots(n+(n-2))(z+i)^{-2n+1} \, ,
$$
confirming your result.

Comment: Thanks once again Martin!